# Overflowing layout with flexbox and bootstrap3 columns causing undesired page width increase

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have a layout making use of [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) columns and [flexbox](/questions/tagged/flexbox).

At a highlevel, the layout I am trying to achieve is like this:

[image: layout overview]

The toolbar and the rest of the content are flexed next to each other (dashed boxes are the children of the flex):

[image: dashed boxes are flexed]

The non-toolbar sections (the green, blue and yellow boxes) are one bootstrap3 row, with three columns (columns are dashed boxes). On large screens the layout should be like the image (meta + main content is `col-md-7`, secondary #1 is `col-md-5`, secondary #2 is `col-md-12`), but defaulting to separate rows on small screens (all `col-sm-12`):

[image: dashed boxes are columns in a bootstrap 3 row]

Finally, the meta and main content (the green and blue boxes) are flexed next to each other (dashed boxes are the children of the flex):

[image: dashed boxes are flexed]

The tricky part is that the main content (the blue section) can get quite wide and must scroll horizontally. The issue I am running into is that as the overflowing content section gets larger, it seems to push the screen artificially wide and escape the boundaries of the bootstrap column.

Here is a simplified example showcasing the issue. (You might have to click "Full page" link to see the overflow issue.)

Is there any way to get around this issue?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-variable {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /*flex:1;*/
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.overflowable-h {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

div {
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <h1>overflowing content</h1>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>toolbar</div>

      <div class="flex-variable">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="text-nowrap">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-variable w-100 text-nowrap overflowable-h">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content-content</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div>secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>no overflowing content</h1>
    <div class="flex">
      <div>toolbar</div>

      <div class="flex-variable">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="text-nowrap">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                    <td>metadata</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-variable w-100 text-nowrap overflowable-h">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>content-content</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>content-content-content</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div>secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary-secondary</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so if content is col-md-7, secondary1 is col-md-5, what is content-metadata and the toolbar? Bootstrap is based on a 12 column layout.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I added more images for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correct, try this:

add and modify your css like below: (toolbar can have any fixed width px/rem/vw/percent and Your flex-variable should calc available width based on toolbar width)

```
#toolbar{width:200px;}
.flex-variable {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

and add id to toolbard div

```
<div id="toolbar">toolbar</div>
```

You can achive this in many ways, but your container should have some width to not overflow.